# Detect and fix many to many in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table "Teaches". This has a PK and a Name.

```
mysql> Select * from Teacher;
+-----+---------+
| TID | Tname   |
+-----+---------+
|   1 | RC      |
|   2 | Dinesha |
|   3 | JLT     |
+-----+---------+
```

I have another Table "TeachesSubject". It has _surrid which is a PK, the TID references Teacher and SName is the Name of the subject taught.

```
mysql> select * from TeachesSubject;
+---------+------+-------+
| _surrid | TID  | SNAME |
+---------+------+-------+
|     100 |    1 | DBMS  |
|     101 |    1 | DM    |
|     102 |    2 | DBMS  |
|     103 |    2 | OOAD  |
|     104 |    3 | OOAD  |
|     105 |    3 | SE    |
+---------+------+-------+
```

These two tables are already populated. I now run a query in TeachesSubject that points out the SNAMEs with duplicate values.

```
mysql>  select SNAME from TeachesSubject group by SNAME having count(*)>1;
+-------+
| SNAME |
+-------+
| DBMS  |
| OOAD  |
+-------+
```

Once I detect this, I want my sql script to create a new table:

```
Teaches
_surrId TID
100      1
101      1
100      2
103      2
103      3
105      3
```

My old Teaches Subject Must look like

```
mysql> select * from TeachesSubject;
+---------+------+
| _surrid | SNAME |
+---------+-------+
|     100 | DBMS  |
|     101 | DM    |
|     103 | OOAD  |
|     105 | SE    |
+---------+------+
```

How Do I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear as it seems to use `Teaches` and `Teachers` as the name of the same table. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
CREATE TABLE TeachesSubject2
 (`_surrid` int, `SNAME` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO TeachesSubject2
  SELECT MIN(_surrid), sname
  FROM TeachesSubject
  GROUP BY sname
  ;

CREATE TABLE Teaches
 (`_surrid` int, `TID` int)
 ;

 INSERT INTO Teaches
  SELECT t2._surrid, t1.tid
  FROM TeachesSubject AS t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TeachesSubject2 AS t2
  ON t1.sname = t2.sname
  ;
```

Working example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13d417/2

In future it would help if you created a fiddle yourself and attempted to write the SQL yourself. Then I wouldn't have to spend my time setting up for the answer, I could just fix whatever problem you are having.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! :) I have to make this happen dynamically now. You're awesome. :D